# Unable to get multiple Slick carousels to work on a single page

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I have three carousels on a single page of a website. Two of them use the same configuration, so they work fine when I use the following code;

```
$('.carousel .items').slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: false,
        speed: 300,
        arrows: false,
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2,
        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 576,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    slidesToScroll: 1
                }
            }
        ]
    });
```

I need to add another carousel which shows more items, so I've given it a unique Id and tried to add the following code;

```
$('#buildings-for-sale .items').slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: false,
        speed: 300,
        arrows: false,
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 4,
        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 576,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    slidesToScroll: 1
                }
            }
        ]
    });
```

The problem is, only the carousel that's defined first in the Javascript works, not both different configurations at the same time.

I've tried to initial each slider inside an each() loop and using a data-tag to make the necessary amendments, and while this gets all of the sliders rendering correctly the slider that shows four elements does not slide to the next set of results correctly, it just shows a blank screen. Here's the code I tried;

```
$('.carousel .items').each(function(idx, item){
        var slides = $(this).attr('data-slides');
        if (!slides > 0) {
            slides = 2;
        }

        console.log("Slides " + slides);

        $(this).slick({
            dots: true,
            infinite: false,
            speed: 300,
            arrows: false,
            slidesToShow: slides,
            slidesToScroll: slides,
            responsive: [
                {
                    breakpoint: 576,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 1,
                        slidesToScroll: 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    });
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I might get this working?

Comment: have you tried using both with no options? just bog-standard defaults?

Comment: does `#buildings-for-sale` also have the `.carousel` class?

Comment: I hadn't, but as a result of me checking, I found the problem.

Comment: @Alex yes, that was the problem. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your comment, the easiest way probably is excluding the third carousel from the first function call:

```
$('.carousel:not(#buildings-for-sale) .items').slick({
```